# Create dynamically FormArray fields in a form in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, formarray

I am learning about FormArray to make a dynamic form. My problem is that I have to relate the fields in the formarray to a selected item in a multiple selection dropdown. Let's say I select an option called 'Foo', then 3 fields to give information about Foo will be created, and more can be created, therefore FormArray.

So, I have followed this tutotial to learn a bit about it https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/ but my problem is that this works only if the FormArray field is defined in the form since the begining. What I am doing to relate the selected option and its fields is creating field dynamically in its form like this:

```
const idCategoria: string =  '1';
this.indicadorModal.addControl('objetivo.' + idCategoria, new FormGroup(
    {
        objetivos: this.fb.array([this.crearObjetoObjetivo()])
    }
));
```

this will cause that indicadorModal (which is a FormGroup) will have fields like, for example, objetivo.1 , objetivo.2, etc. BUT NOW I need these to be form array but I dont seem to be able to do what in the tutorial I liked says, it says that the control doesn't exist. Is there something wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share you current code - preferably in a stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Ulises, I think you're mixing concepts. A dinamic Form can be a FormArray or a FormGroup. I think, your'e looking for FormGroup, so, take a look to the [docs about FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)

If you has a FormGroup and an array of objects

```
  myForm=new FormGroup({})
  fields:any[]=[];
```

You can add formControl to the formGroup using addControl, e.g.

```
addFields()
{
     this.myForm.addControl('name',new FormControl())
     this.myForm.addControl('surname',new FormControl())

     this.fields.push({name:'name',label:'Name'})
     this.fields.push({name:'surname',label:'Surname'})
}
```

And you can iterate over the array fields in your .html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
    {{field.label}}:<input [formControlName]="field.name">
  </div>
</form>
```

See that it's not a FormArray but is "dynamic"

See the code [in simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzucyk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)